# Replace Content Controls with text

Tags: java, docx4j

[I need to replace content controls with text in word document using docx4j](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaU9c.png)

[I refer this link ,I'm not able to understand how to get .xml file from .docx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28537411/word-docx4j-and-content-control-text-formatting) 
Does anyone know where I can find code examples of this?

Answer (score 1):

```
    private static void replaceTextValue(WordprocessingMLPackage template, String name, String placeholder)
        throws Exception {

    List<Object> texts = getAllElementFromObject(template.getMainDocumentPart(), SdtBlock.class);
    // System.out.println(template.getMainDocumentPart().getXML());
    for (Object text : texts) {
        SdtBlock textElement = (SdtBlock) text;
        List<Object> cList = textElement.getSdtContent().getContent();
        ClassFinder finder = new ClassFinder(Text.class);
        new TraversalUtil(cList, finder);
        for (Object o : finder.results) {
            Object o2 = XmlUtils.unwrap(o);
            if (o2 instanceof org.docx4j.wml.Text) {
                String CTagVal = ((org.docx4j.wml.Text) o2).getValue();

                if (CTagVal.equalsIgnoreCase(placeholder)) {
                    org.docx4j.wml.Text txt = (org.docx4j.wml.Text) o2;
                    txt.setValue(name);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println(XmlUtils.marshaltoString(o, true, true));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*this method replace the text inside the control*

Answer (score 0):

I'm working through content controls in docx4j myself. If you just want to view the xml of a docx file, you can replace the .docx file extention with .zip which is essentially what it is. Then go into the zip file and you will find the underlying xml. I believe there are apps that will allow you to edit and save docx xml, but havent looked into that much.

If you want to insert a content control in a word template, you first need to turn on the developer tab. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608625.aspx . This will add a Controls section under the developer tab. see: https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/content_controls.html

I haven't found a good example of doing the actual variable replacement with the controls only with XmlUtils.unmarshallFromTemplate(xmlString , mappings) which seems to have a lot of quarks. If you work that part out, please post.

Comment: Thanks...i just want to replace placeholder text with given value in .docx file